# Is Ajax a safe way to pass data

Tags: python, html

I am trying to use Ajax to send data from the user input to the backend of my site but I was wondering if this was the right way to pass data from the front to the end? Does this pose any security issues? If so please tell me the safe alternatives to passing data from the front to the back. Thank you and have a nice day.

Comment: Please mention the web framework you use.

Comment: I am using Flask

Comment: Use AJAX to make a request to that function.

Answer (score 0):

You can not link a python script to an HTML document.

If you want to use python for front-end scripts, please read about [pyodide](https://pyodide.org/en/stable/).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply assign it to location instead of location.href and pass x as argument.

```
location='/validate_comment?rendezook='+x
```